# I get a "Attempt to execute non instruction" in qtspim?

Tags: assembly, qtspim

Could someone help me figure out what's wrong with my code? I am trying to read an integer, store its value and print it to the screen/

```
.text

main:

li $v0, 5
la $a0, testInteger
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, resultString
syscall

li $v0, 1    
la $a0, testInteger
syscall

.data

testInteger: .word 5
resultString: .ascii "The integer is :"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to signal that the end of your program has been reached. In SPIM and its offshoots you do this [with `syscall` number 10](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html).

So when you want execution of your program to stop (e.g. after you've printed the integer) you do:

```
li $v0, 10   # syscall 10 = exit    
syscall
```

---

Some other issues in your code:

1. `syscall` number 5 returns the read integer in `$v0`. It does not store it in the memory pointed to by `$a0` like your code seems to assume.
2. `syscall` number 1 expects the value of the integer to print in `$a0`. You're putting *the address* of the integer in `$a0` (that's what `la` does).